# Magento 2 Warning: Division by zero : vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Item.php

Tags: magento2.2.6, exception, error-log

Please Advise on it,
i got this error,

```
main.CRITICAL: Warning: Division by zero in vendor/magento/module- 
 sales/Model/Order/Item.php on line 411 {"exception":"[object] 
 (Exception(code: 0): Warning: Division by zero in 
  vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Item.php on line 411
```

Comment: I see that you are throwing on this website a lot of "questions" that just contain an error message. No explanation, no nothing. Please stop. Try to give some context to your problems, like explaining how to reproduce them and what have you tried to fix them.